# Changing attribute table values to scientific notation using ArcGIS Pro

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcgis-pro

I have an attribute table that I would like to format. I need to display the numerical values in scientific notation (ie 2.367E-02 instead of 0.02367).

How can I do this in ArcGIS Pro version 2.7?

Answer (score 1):

I am currently stuck using the old ArcMap 10.6, but you can format the numbers in the attribute table by right clicking on the field that contains your numeric data, going into the properties, and then changing the number format to "Scientific".

There should be an equivalent procedure in ArcGIS Pro.

Comment: Thank you! Do you know if there is a way to do this for multiple fields at a time?

Comment: There does not appear to be a way to access it via arcpy, and the documentation for formatting numeric fields doesn't say too much. You may be stuck doing it manually

Comment: The formatting options that Adam mentioned are available if you right-click the table and go to "Design -> Fields". But one at a time as far as I can see.

Answer (score 0):

I wanted to update this thread as the software has changed. I did not quickly see a way to do this automatically in ArcPy, but manually now, instead of going to design or properties, you go to fields view (where you add fields, change alias, etc). There is a column for Number Format there. You can select various number options, including scientific notation.